# R issues with mutate

Tags: r

I should start by saying that I am completely frustrated with R at this point. I have spent at least 15 hours trying to figure out this simple problem and was up until 2 am last night with it.

I get that this is a really powerful program but mutate is really almost impossible to figure out -- All I want is to create a plot of dates versus counts- I import my .csv file, convert it to a data frame, create the variables, summarize them, and graph them.
And I realize this is verbose so -- to the person who will be yelling at me about that - my apologies but I wanted people to see where the data was being outputted

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    req(varY())
    oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref2.csv")
    DF <- data.frame(oboler_data)} 
    log <- DF %>% mutate(Date = date %>% as.character() %>% ymd)
    # create variables of the week and month of each observation:
    log$Year <- as.date(cut(log$date,
                            breaks = "year"))
    log$Month <- as.date(cut(log$date,
                             breaks = "month"))
    log$Week <- as.date(cut(log$date,
                            breaks = "week",
                            start.on.monday = FALSE)) # changes weekly break point to Sunday
    
    output$selUI = renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "varSel",
                    label = "Transaction Types",
                    choices = oboler_data %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% tbl_vars)
    })
    
    varY = reactive({
        req(input$varSel)
        input$varSel
    })
    
    plotDiam = reactive({
        req(varY())
        oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref2.csv")
        DF <- data.frame(oboler_data)
           
        # graph by month:
        ggplot(DF = log$Month,
               aes(varY(),month)) +
            stat_summary(fun.y = sum, # adds up all observations for the month
                         geom = "bar") + # or "line"
            scale_x_date(
                labels = date_format("%Y-%m"),
                breaks = "1 month") # custom x-axis labels
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        plotDiam()
        
    })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Not clear without a reproducible example Perhaps `DF %>% mutate(Date = ymd(date))`  there is a typo in the code `as.Date` instead of `as.date`

Comment: I agree with @akrun, and also, it may be that you need to provide a format for the `as.Date(data, format = "%m-%d-%Y")` , or whatever format your date is actually in, if it is '/' then replace the - with / .

Comment: The data is just date y—m-d followed by columns like email chat zoom with integers  2020-6-1 45 56 67 2020-7-1 45 34 23.

Answer (score 0):

One way for beginning R users to reduce their frustration with R is to break a problem down into smaller components, and assemble a larger solution by combining the working subcomponents.

In the case of the question posed above, one could perform the data transformations and figure out how to produce the bar chart outside Shiny, then integrate the working charting solution into a Shiny app.

To illustrate how to create a bar chart with `ggplot2` we will generate some sample data and use `ggplot()` with the `geom_bar()` geometry.

```
date <- c("2020-06-01","2020-06-02","2020-06-03","2020-06-04","2020-06-05")
count <- c(35,44,23,57,62)

df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(date,"%Y-%m-%d"),count)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=count)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

...and the output:

[image]

### Additional considerations for new R users

Sometimes the `tidyverse` family of packages can be overwhelming due to the large number of functions that need to be learned to do something useful. In general, you want to start with the simplest code possible instead of building lengthy `tidyverse` pipelines.

For example, once the raw data file is read into R with `read_csv()`, one can convert the character based date field into a date with the following code, assuming that the character field is YYYY-MM-DD in the CSV file.

```
oboler_data$date <- as.Date(oboler_data$date,"%Y-%m-%d)
```

That said, [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) applies even within the `tidyverse`. For example, here we eliminate the pipeline within `mutate()` that was posted in the original question.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date,"%Y-%m-%d))
```

If we add `lubridate` package, we can calculate the `year`, `month` and `day` variables in a single `mutate()` call as follows.

```
date <- c("2020-06-01","2020-06-02","2020-06-03","2020-06-04","2020-06-05")
count <- c(35,44,23,57,62)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date,count,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df %>% 
     mutate(date = ymd(date),
          Year = year(date),
          Month = month(date),
          Day = day(date))
```

...and the output:

```
        date count Year Month Day
1 2020-06-01    35 2020     6   1
2 2020-06-02    44 2020     6   2
3 2020-06-03    23 2020     6   3
4 2020-06-04    57 2020     6   4
5 2020-06-05    62 2020     6   5
>
```

Comment: I don’t disagree. My issue is I need to create a fairly complex application quickly while learning R from scratch.  If I can get this to plot data by month that’s all I need.  The goal is a plot that changes based on the pull down menu.

Comment: @KarlBridges - If you can make your data available (e.g. upload it to a public Github repository [like this example csv file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/06-20-2020.csv), or create some simulated data and include via `dput()` in your question), the community can help you get your Shiny app working.